# Expect errors AND other status in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

In an Rspec test, I want to expect an error. However, I also want to expect that the code makes (or does not make) some changes before I get to that error.

I have something like this:

```
it 'raises a VeryBad::NotCool error' do
  expect { instance.err! }.to raise_error(VeryBad::NotCool)
end
```

This passes. However, when I do:

```
it 'changes the instance status' do
  expect{ instance.err! }.to change{ instance.name }
    .from('nice instance').to('erroring instamce')
end
```

This fails, because

```
Failure/Error: raise VeryBad::NotCool
```

The failure makes sense. 
However, on the other hand, I think it is also useful to be able to check if a change happened before we get to the error, since the code could be something like:

```
def err!
  instance.name = 'erroring instance'
  raise VeryBad::NotCool if instance.save!
end
```

How can I check if the change happened even if there is an (expected) error raised during the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
it 'raises a VeryBad::NotCool error' do
  expect(instance.name).to eq 'old_value'
  expect { instance.err! }.to raise_error(VeryBad::NotCool)
  expect(instance.reload.name).to eq 'erroring instance'
end
```